# Git flow feature finish options - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, git-flow

I'm using git flow for the first time in Eclipse. When I click on publish feature, I got a dialog box asking to choose between two options as shown below. Can anyone explain me what are these options mean?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? 1. The dialog box you show is for finishing a feature, which should be different than publishing a feature. 2. The descriptions in the screenshot seem fairly self-explanatory; what part is confusing to you?